# apex cpu time limit exceeded error in salesforce

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app, cpulimit

How can i handle this error in salesforce ? i know that it occurs due
to inner loops

my code is

```
for(tblproperty__c t:CheckAvailability)
{
   for(tblpropertyamenities__c te: CheckPropertyAmenity)
  {
    if(t.fPropertyID__c==te.fPropertyIDDB__c)
     {
      CheckAvailability1.add(t);
      }
 }
}
```

Comment: The Maximum CPU time on the salesforce servers is used to stop long running processes. The error will be thrown at some point after your code has been running for 10,000 milliseconds (60,000 for Asynchronous code). The line the error happens on does not mean that line is the problem. Your code looks fine and shouldn't of caused this error. There is most likely code that executed before that code that caused the problem.

Comment: How many records are in `CheckPropertyAmenity` and `CheckAvailability`?

Comment: 1173 records in both

Comment: Your loop will iterate 1,375,929 times (1,173 x 1,173). Are you limiting your SOQL with a where clause so that you are only selecting certain records or are you selecting all records? Providing a bit more of your code may help other people understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

If both lists are large then performance will degrade exponentially. You can change the performance to be linear with the number of list items like this:

```
Set<Id> propertyIds= new Set<Id>();
for(tblpropertyamenities__c te : CheckPropertyAmenity) {
    propertyIds.add(te.fPropertyIDDB__c);
}
for(tblproperty__c t : CheckAvailability) {
    if (propertyIds.contains(t.fPropertyID__c)) {
        CheckAvailability1.add(t);
    }
}
```

(If you needed access to the tblpropertyamenities__c fields, instead of creating a `Set<Id>` you could create a `Map<Id, tblpropertyamenities__c>`.)

Though it would be a little surprising to hit the CPU limit unless the lists are very large.

Comment: i got it, i have done it through adding break statement in my if condition when true

Comment: @RiazMuhammad That will reduce the amount of time by a factor of 2 on average so when the list gets 2 times bigger than it is now the problem will return...